# Cast array beyond the first level

Tags: php, arrays, casting

Hi I have a std class object with objects in it, when I cast it as an array, only the first level is changed to an array. Is there a why to cast the sub-objects as arrays too?

var_dump($heyo);

```
object(stdClass)#167 (27) { 
    ["uid"]=> object(stdClass)#166 (1) { 
        ["1"]=> int(15)
```

var_dump((array)($heyo));

```
array(27) { 
    ["uid"]=> object(stdClass)#166 (1) { 
        ["1"]=> int(15)
```

Comment: could you show us some sample code?

Comment: I would love some more details. How do you cast? What does the object look like? Is it of variable depth, or is it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I found this function at [if-not-true-then-false.com](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/)

```
function objectToArray($d) {
    if (is_object($d)) {
        // Gets the properties of the given object
        // with get_object_vars function
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }

    if (is_array($d)) {
        /*
        * Return array converted to object
        * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    }
    else {
        // Return array
        return $d;
    }
}
```

It'll recursively convert your stdClass objects to arrays